# multiprocessing ThreadPool stops at the end

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool

I wrote a script that "parses" all domains from the file. After the launch, everything works as it should. But when there are several domains left at the end, it gets stuck. Sometimes it takes a long time to parse the last couple of domains. I can't figure out what the problem is. Who has faced such a situation? Tell me how to cure it.

After the launch, everything works out very quickly (as it should) until the end. At the end, it stops when there are several domains left. There is no difference, **1000** domains or **10 000** domains.

Complete code:

```
import re
import sys
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

pool = 100

with open("Rules.json") as file:
    REGEX = json.loads(file.read())

ua = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'}

def Domain_checker(domain):
    try:
        r = requests.get("http://" + domain, verify=False, headers=ua)
        r.encoding = "utf-8"

        for company in REGEX.keys():

            for type in REGEX[company]:
                check_entry = 0

                for ph_regex in REGEX[company][type]:
                    if bool(re.search(ph_regex, r.text)) is True:
                        check_entry += 1

                        if check_entry == len(REGEX[company][type]):
                            title = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
                            Found_domain = "\nCompany: {0}\nRule: {1}\nURL: {2}\nTitle: {3}\n".format(company, type, r.url, title.title.text)
                            print(Found_domain)
                            with open("/tmp/__FOUND_DOMAINS__.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8', errors = 'ignore') as file:
                                file.write(Found_domain)

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL:
        pass
    except UnicodeError:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError:
        pass
    except requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError:
        pass
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return domain


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with open(sys.argv[1], "r", encoding='utf-8', errors = 'ignore') as file:
        Domains = file.read().split()

    pool = 100
    print("Pool = ", pool)

    results = ThreadPool(pool).imap_unordered(Domain_checker, Domains)
    string_num = 0

    for result in results:
        print("{0} => {1}".format(string_num, result))
        string_num += 1

    with open("/tmp/__FOUND_DOMAINS__.txt", encoding='utf-8', errors = 'ignore') as found_domains:
        found_domains = found_domains.read()

    print("{0}\n{1}".format("#" * 40, found_domains))
```

Comment: One of those except blocks is likely suppressing the exception that's being raised. At least print the exceptions.

Comment: There are no errors due to ThreadPool in the exceptions. Only exceptions that are associated with the unavailability of a domain, encoding and so on

Comment: Alligat0r: Since you're suppressing all those Exceptions, you can't know what's causing them. BTW, you can handle multiple Exceptions the same way in one `except` clause by creating a tuple of them: i.e. `except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects, etc...):`.

Answer (score 0):

```
requests.get("http://" + domain, headers=ua, verify=False, timeout=10)
```

The problem is resolved after installing **timeout**

Thank you to the user with the nickname "**eri**" (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16574/eri) :)